# hard coded predefined values in xtext

Tags: java, parsing, xtext

starting fro here http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation.html#DomainModelWalkThrough
I would like to add some predefined type strings so that

```
entity ent{
    d:INTEGERS
}
```

is legal.  Without the declare statment

```
datatype INTEGERS
```

I have tried

```
Type:
    DataType | Entity | value=PredefType;

enum PredefType: INTEGERS='INTEGERS' | STRING='STRING';
```

and

```
Type:
    DataType | Entity | PredefType;

PredefType:
    name='INTEGERS' | name='STRING';
```

but neither work.

Sorry if the question is silly, I'm new to xtext.

Answer (score 0):

```
Type:
DataType | Entity | PredefType;

PredefType: type=SimpleType;

enum SimpleType: INTEGERS='INTEGERS' | STRING='STRING';
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.  In the generated plugin I get a compilation error "mismatched input 'INTEGERS' expecting RULE_ID"